# Encapsulation issue with fields

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i have abstract 'Unit' class and other non-abstract classes like 'Player' and 'Mage' heirs this 'Unit' class.

In 'Unit' class i have some fields witch has to be private, like maxHp, speed and so on. Because of privacy of these fields i can`t to set value to them directly in the 'Player' script. So i have to call this method inside Parent ('Unit') script. But i don't want to have 'SetPlayerLoadedValues' method in other classes like 'Mage'.

Thanks for your replys and sorry for bad English.

```
// This is somewhere inside the abstract 'Unit' class.
protected virtual void SetPlayerLoadedValues(PlayerController player)
{
    var playerData = SaveLoadSystem.LoadPlayerData();

    if (playerData != null)
    {
        player.damage = playerData.damage;
        player.maxHp = playerData.maxHp;
        player.currentHp = playerData.currentHp;
        player.speed = playerData.speed;
    }
}


// This is somewhere inside the non-abstract 'Player' class.
protected override void SetPlayerLoadedValues(PlayerController player)
{
    base.SetPlayerLoadedValues(player);

    var playerData = SaveLoadSystem.LoadPlayerData();

    if (playerData != null)
    {
        player.maxMana = playerData.maxMana;
        player.currentMana = playerData.currentMana;
    }

    transform.position = RespawnPoint.RespawnPosition;
}
```

Comment: If these fileds are private in `Unit` then why they needed in the inherited classes? Or what responsibility they have? I don't see what is the reason behind this decision. Possibly, you should explain whys and whats, so we can understand it and help.

Comment: @AndrasCsanyi Because i have to SetPlayerLoadedValues when player instantiated

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to set the fields to `protected` not `private`. This will mean that you can access it from classes that inherit from it, but not others:

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class
> instances.

Comment: I want to only get values from fields like 'maxHp' from Player script. I don`t want to make those fields protected. That will broke my encapsulation in project.